# Compiling Ada library for Android (JNI)

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, arm, java-native-interface, ada

I have written an application in Ada and I want to run it on Android (ARM devices). I have compiled a native standalone library for ARM (arm64-v8a) on a Raspberry Pi, containing the proper JNI. However, when I launch the application in Android it fails while loading the library (right on the System.loadLibrary call).
Is there something theoretically wrong in proceeding this way, or should it work?

Before doing this experiment on android, I successfully loaded an Ada test library on Java using a x64 PC, so I don't think the problem is in the interface itself.
I would have expected the library to be loaded without issues.

*For the full code to see what I am trying to do, please, have a look at GuillermoHazebrouck/gnav on GitHub.*

Comment: Did you use a toolchain that specifically targets Android when building the library? If not, that's probably the problem. You can't just take an .so file built for some generic Linux, even if targets the same CPU architecture.

Comment: I was afraid of that. So, any idea of how to target Android while compiling then?

Comment: I am linking libGLESv2 and libC. Other libraries appear when calling readelf, but I don't make explicit calls to them, so far I know and at least with the symbols I was trying to use.

Comment: Normally one would use the Android NDK, but I have no idea how to incorporate that when building Ada code.

Answer (score 3):

There were some threads on comp.lang.ada about this, about ten years ago. From memory, then, best progress was with the Dragonfly BSD Unix builds of gcc with gnat enabled. I could build standalone Ada console apps that way and run them on a tablet.

[Dragonlace compiler project here](http://www.dragonlace.net/)

Interfacing with Java/GUI etc requires the NDK, following the NDK demos using C++ code or libraries. However I neither managed to get the NDK to recognise the Dragonfly BSD gnat compiler, nor to rebuild the NDK gcc with --enable-languages=c,c++,ada : either path resulted in a string of errors I couldn't resolve.

Last time I looked, a few years ago, the NDK was deprecating gcc in favour of LLVM, and at the time, there was no Ada front end for the LLVM compiler (though funnily enough, there is a [VHDL front end for LLVM, written in Ada!](https://ghdl.github.io/ghdl/development/building/LLVM.html))

Separately I believe Adacore now has a Gnat release with an LLVM backend, at least as an internal product, thought I don't know if that has been released to the FSF Gnat tree yet.

[Gnat/LLVM on Github here.](https://github.com/AdaCore/gnat-llvm)

[Further info from Adacore here.](https://blog.adacore.com/combining-gnat-with-llvm)

[Old comp.lang.ada thread on Gnat/LLVM here.](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.ada/c/umrsksm3nEs?pli=1)

But I think you're looking at either convincing a recent NDK to still recognise GCC, and then either :

- building that GCC with Gnat enabled
- convincing NDK to work with an external Gnat enabled gcc

Or combining the NDK's LLVM compiler with Adacore's Gnat/LLVM frontend.

None of these approaches are trivial.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the LLVM :-/
I am building a native interface compatible with JNI, and I just want my Android program to load it and use it. In Linux it seems to work. But as Michael said, I now understand that the compilation does not only need to target the right architecture, but also Android. I think the question is how to compile the library for Android instead of Linux. No?

Comment: Right ... as far as I know. But to do that, you *probably* need the compiler integrated in the Android NDK toolkit. Which used to be gcc, but is now LLVM (for C and C++). Yes I'm hoping someone will come along with better news too.

Answer (score 0):

> when I launch the application in Android it fails while loading the
> library (right on the System.loadLibrary call). Is there something
> theoretically wrong in proceeding this way, or should it work?

I'm not sure why the load-library call would fail if it's (a) stored in the proper format, and (b) using the proper machine code. When it is loaded, though, you may have to manually call the initialization function (IIRC `adainit`).

Several years ago, someone had a problem with Ada in libraries, and it came down to that initialization immediately after loading it, and also a call to the finalization (`adafinal`?) when it was finished, IIRC to free the memory/tasks the library had started.

Comment: When linking a standalone library, init and finit are called automatically. I have tested that with Java in my Linux development machine and it really works. I guess the problem is either that the library is not found or not properly recognized by Android. Do you know which compiler was used in those cases you mention? If you want you can take a look at my project, it is open source and hosted in GitHub. Search for GuillermoHazebrouck/gnav

Comment: @gada — I'm sorry, but I don't recall exactly where I read about the problem. I *think* it was either here on SO or else on CLA (Comp.Lang.Ada). I'll ask on Freenode's #Ada channel about it, because someone else might remember.